# ACL for DHCP configured on Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, dhcp, acl

We have a DHCP pool configured on Cisco L3 switch for hosts on SVI.
Since we want to restrict connectivity to DHCP which is on the same switch.

excluded 172.24.19.1-172.24.19.50
SVI IP 172.24.19.50
DHCP gateway 172.24.19.50

Without acl the ipconfig output shows DHCP server as 172.24.19.50
Tried below acl but clients fail to get IP

permit ip any 172.24.19.0 0.0.0.255

permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 172.24.19.50 0.0.0.0

Direction- IN on SVI

what acl should be defined on vlan interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow DHCP:

```
ip access-list extended ACL-DHCP-NET
permit udp any host 255.255.255.255 eq 67 68
<other rules>
```

To reject DHCP:

```
ip access-list extended ACL-STATIC-NET:
deny udp any host 255.255.255.255 eq 67 68
<other rules>
```